# How to redirect link using any browser extention or other techniques

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome-extensions

if user type **www.demo.com** in address bar i want user to redirect to my affiliate link **www.demo.com/?affid=omkar** i tried many things but nothing helped me . Any Help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for this behavior on computers (browsers) in your control? Or any one

Comment: it can be any thing redirection through browser extention or windows hostfile.

Comment: The hosty file (on windows and on other OS's) works on host names. Thus that would give the same IP for `www.demo.com/?affid=omkar` as for `www.demo.com/?affID=Whatever_I_type_here`.

Comment: would you mind responding to your OP to let us know if my answer below worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it.

1. Create a file called index.html and put it in the root of the directory that is hosting www.demo.com
2. In index.html, enter the following code

> `<html>`
>
> `<head><title></title>`
>
> `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0, URL=www.demo.com/?affid=omkar">`
>
> `</head>`
>
> `<body>`
>
> `</body>`
>
> `</html>`

this will cause anyone who goes to demo.com to be redirected automatically to www.demo.com/?affid=omkar

You can change the amount of time it takes to redirect the person by changing the content="0 to any non zero value.

Comment: I think he's aiming to do it on the client side...

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing this client side?  Why would someone run something client side to redirect themselfs to some affiliate site when they visited his site?  Just trying to understand why the redirect solution I posted would not be preferable.

Comment: I fully agree, but you'll have to bug the OP for that clarification. ;)